# How to allow access to private GitHub repository from code build CDK pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am writing a CDK pipeline in Golang where the CDK build is importing a package from private GitHub repository.

The yaml file which build the CDK project and start the CDK synth command looks like this:

[image]

Error:

```
internal/infrastructure/file.go:10:2: github.com/private-repository/lb@v0.0.0-20220707180825-25060de2ad6d: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/82d62389c6040b63289b711060bd7a3817a57a89b79a0f50ca152ad3d073eca1: exit status 128:
351     Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '11.11.11.11' to the list of known hosts.
352     git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
353     fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
354     
355     Please make sure you have the correct access rights
356     and the repository exists.
357 
358 Subprocess exited with error 1
```

Above is the error I am getting where the pipeline is not able to download the private-repository from GitHub.

Can someone please help why this is happening and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Where does ```GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN``` comes from? You probably have to use Secrets Manager or Parameter Store for this in my opinion. Assuming the token is correct You try to access it through SSH, for which You dont have the SSH key so the permission is denied. Try indeed to use HTTP connection to this repo. Other option would be to use GitHub API.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing issue and here what i found.

1. You have to declare you github token as a secret value.
2. Then add it to your cdk stack with this.

```
new codebuild.GitHubSourceCredentials(this, 'CodeBuildGitHubCreds', {
    accessToken: SecretValue.secretsManager(githubTokenSecretValueName),
});
```

Note:

- Just declare it before you define you codebuild project.